# Filter multiple arrays that are populated using Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase-realtime-database

I have a TextField which works as a SearchView and then my TableView shows my results. The prototype cell of the TableView consists of two Labels. The first label is populated by schoolNameArray. The second label is populated by schoolTownArray + ", " + schoolCountryArray. All 3 arrays are populated via Firebase. Image of the search functionality shown below.

[image: SearchView]

Without the second label, I can filter one array just fine. My issue is I can only make my SearchView filter on one array, not three. E.g. I type 'Academy' and 'Azhar Academy' shows, but if I type 'Bolton' I get "Fatal error: Index out of range" because I haven't been able to populate the filteredSchoolLocationArray correctly.

My Android version of the project retrieves the text from the search box and then handles the filtering within the for loop of the firebase query. How can I do this (or achieve the same result) here using the following code:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var editTextSearch: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewSearch: UITableView!

    var schoolNameArray = [String]()
    var schoolTownArray = [String]()
    var schoolCountryArray = [String]()
    var filteredSchoolNameArray = [String]()
    var filteredSchoolLocationArray = [String]()
    var searching  = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let schoolDatabase = Database.database().reference().child("Timetable")
        schoolDatabase.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let schoolID = child as! DataSnapshot
                let stringApproved = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Approved").value
                if stringApproved as? String == "Yes" {
                    let stringSchoolName = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value as! String
                    let stringSchoolTown = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Town or City").value as! String
                    let stringSchoolCountry = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Country").value as! String
                    self.schoolNameArray.append(stringSchoolName)
                    self.schoolTownArray.append(stringSchoolTown)
                    self.schoolCountryArray.append(stringSchoolCountry)
                }
            }
            self.tableViewSearch.reloadData()
        })
    }
}

extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return filteredSchoolNameArray.count
        } else {
            return schoolNameArray.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let searchItem = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchItem") as! SearchItemCell

        searchItem.searchItemSchoolName.text = schoolNameArray[indexPath.row]
        searchItem.searchItemSchoolLocation.text = schoolTownArray[indexPath.row] + ", " + schoolCountryArray[indexPath.row]

        if searching {
            searchItem.searchItemSchoolName.text = filteredSchoolNameArray[indexPath.row]
            searchItem.searchItemSchoolLocation.text = filteredSchoolLocationArray[indexPath.row]
        } else {
            searchItem.searchItemSchoolName.text = schoolNameArray[indexPath.row]
            searchItem.searchItemSchoolLocation.text = schoolTownArray[indexPath.row] + ", " + schoolCountryArray[indexPath.row]
        }

        return searchItem
    }
}

extension SearchViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {    
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        filteredSchoolNameArray = schoolNameArray.filter({$0.lowercased().contains((textField.text?.lowercased())!)})
        searching = true
        tableViewSearch.reloadData()
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using a struct to represent your data. You'll have a much easier time. You have a few more kinks to work out but this should get you going:

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    struct School {
        let name: String
        let town: String
        let country: String
    }

    @IBOutlet weak var editTextSearch: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewSearch: UITableView!

    var schools: [School] = []
    var filteredSchools: [School] = []

    var searching = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // ...

        if stringApproved as? String == "Yes" {
            let name = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value as! String
            let town = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Town or City").value as! String
            let country = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Country").value as! String

            self.schools.append(.init(name: name, town: town, country: country))
        }

        // ...
    }

    // ...
}

extension SearchViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
        filteredSchools = schools.filter({ $0.name.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) })
        searching = true
        tableViewSearch.reloadData()
        return true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Rob for his help, below is the final code.

```
class SearchViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var editTextSearch: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var tableViewSearch: UITableView!

    struct School {
        let schoolName: String
        let schoolTown: String
        let schoolCountry: String
    }

    var schoolArray: [School] = []
    var filteredSchoolArray: [School] = []
    var searching  = false

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        let schoolDatabase = Database.database().reference().child("Timetable")
        schoolDatabase.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
            for child in snapshot.children {
                let schoolID = child as! DataSnapshot
                let stringApproved = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Approved").value
                if stringApproved as? String == "Yes" {
                    // stringSchoolID = schoolID.key
                    let stringSchoolName = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Name").value as! String
                    let stringSchoolTown = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Town or City").value as! String
                    let stringSchoolCountry = schoolID.childSnapshot(forPath: "Country").value as! String
                    self.schoolArray.append(.init(schoolName: stringSchoolName, schoolTown: stringSchoolTown, schoolCountry: stringSchoolCountry))
                }
            }
            self.tableViewSearch.reloadData()
        })
        //filteredSchoolArray.removeAll()
    }
}

extension SearchViewController: UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if searching {
            return filteredSchoolArray.count
        } else {
            return schoolArray.count
        }
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let searchItem = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SearchItem") as! SearchItemCell

        if searching {
            let filteredSchoolItem = filteredSchoolArray[indexPath.row]
            searchItem.searchItemSchoolName.text = filteredSchoolItem.schoolName
            searchItem.searchItemSchoolLocation.text = filteredSchoolItem.schoolTown + ", " + filteredSchoolItem.schoolCountry
        } else {
            let schoolItem = schoolArray[indexPath.row]
            searchItem.searchItemSchoolName.text = schoolItem.schoolName
            searchItem.searchItemSchoolLocation.text = schoolItem.schoolTown + ", " + schoolItem.schoolCountry
        }

        return searchItem
    }
}

extension SearchViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
    func textFieldShouldClear(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        editTextSearch.resignFirstResponder()
        editTextSearch.text = ""
        filteredSchoolArray.removeAll()
        tableViewSearch.reloadData()
        return true
    }

    func textField(_ textField: UITextField, shouldChangeCharactersIn range: NSRange, replacementString string: String) -> Bool {
        guard let text = textField.text else { return true }
        filteredSchoolArray = schoolArray.filter({$0.schoolName.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) ||
            $0.schoolTown.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased()) ||
            $0.schoolCountry.lowercased().contains(text.lowercased())})
        searching = true
        tableViewSearch.reloadData()
        return true
    }
}
```